# whats wrong in my code its giving parse error

Tags: php, google-oauth, parse-error, php-parse-error

This code is giving parse error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING` at line `$gender=$user['gender'];` .....whats wrong in this code...need help.....thanks

```
<?php
 require_once 'config/functions.php';
 session_start();
 $user=$_SESSION['google_data'];
 if(!empty($user)){
  $email = $user['email'];
  $fname = $user['given_name'];
  $lname = $user['family_name'];
  $gender=$user['gender'];
  $dob = $user['birthday'];
  $location = '';
  $picture = $user['picture'];
  $uid = $user['id'];
  $ousername = '';
  $link = $user['link'];
       $provider = 'google';
       $verified = $user['verified_email'];

      $gen=0;
      if($gender == 'male'){$gen=1;} else{$gen=0;}
      $new_dob = date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($dob) );

      $userObj = new User();
      $userdata = $userObj->checkUser($email,$fname,$lname,$gen,$new_dob,$location,$picture,$uid,$ousername,$link,$provider,$new_verified); 
      if(!empty($userdata)){         
        $_SESSION['id'] = $userdata['user_id'];
        $_SESSION['oauth_id'] = $userdata['user_oauth_id'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $userdata['user_oauth_username'];
        $_SESSION['picture'] = $userdata['picture'];            
        $_SESSION['link'] = $userdata['link'];
        $_SESSION['fname'] = $userdata['user_fname'];
        $_SESSION['lname'] = $userdata['user_lname'];
        $_SESSION['gender'] = $userdata['user_gender'];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $userdata['user_email'];
        $_SESSION['oauth_provider'] = $userdata['user_oauth_provider'];             
        $_SESSION['oauth_id'] = $uid;


     } else {
        # For testing purposes, if there was an error, let's kill the script
        die("There was an error.");

    }
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: problem is not in there post entire page code...

Comment: ok posting entire page

Comment: i have added answer have a look

Comment: Can you double check which line is causing the error - or even if it's in this codefile.  There does not seem to be anything obviously wrong with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `}` from the last becaues that is extra.

so final line will be.

```
} else {
      # For testing purposes, if there was an error, let's kill the script
      die("There was an error.");
 }
```

**CompleteCode**

```
<?php
    require_once 'config/functions.php';
    session_start();
    $user=$_SESSION['google_data'];

    if(!empty($user))
    {
        $email = $user['email'];
        $fname = $user['given_name'];
        $lname = $user['family_name'];
        $gender=$user['gender'];
        $dob = $user['birthday'];
        $location = '';
        $picture = $user['picture'];
        $uid = $user['id'];
        $ousername = '';
        $link = $user['link'];
        $provider = 'google';
        $verified = $user['verified_email'];

        $gen=0;
        if($gender == 'male'){$gen=1;} else{$gen=0;}

        $new_dob = date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($dob) );

        $userObj = new User();
        $userdata = $userObj->checkUser($email,$fname,$lname,$gen,$new_dob,$location,$picture,$uid,$ousername,$link,$provider,$new_verified); 

        if(!empty($userdata))
        {
            $_SESSION['id'] = $userdata['user_id'];
            $_SESSION['oauth_id'] = $userdata['user_oauth_id'];
            $_SESSION['username'] = $userdata['user_oauth_username'];
            $_SESSION['picture'] = $userdata['picture'];            
            $_SESSION['link'] = $userdata['link'];
            $_SESSION['fname'] = $userdata['user_fname'];
            $_SESSION['lname'] = $userdata['user_lname'];
            $_SESSION['gender'] = $userdata['user_gender'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $userdata['user_email'];
            $_SESSION['oauth_provider'] = $userdata['user_oauth_provider'];             
            $_SESSION['oauth_id'] = $uid;

        }
    }
    else
    {
        die("There was an error.");
    }
?>
```

Comment: already removed...still getting error

Comment: @vikasdevde copy paste my code and then try....if still same then look inside function.php file which is included

Comment: that worked...hows that possible ....you just added else for outer "if" instead of the inner one and it started working....can you please tell me how it worked?

Comment: @vikasdevde because you had extra } at the end of script...do not thanx me say thanx to notepad++ which gave me visual about which brace is extra...BTW always welcome bro

Comment: Thanks....I was about to cry after wasting 2 hours on it...many thanks

Comment: @vikasdevde always welcome bro...even we are from same country i guess..

Answer (score 1):

This line might be the issue:

```
     }
     } else {
```

Comment: removed that but still error...

Comment: is there any other thing that is syntactically wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

Please use like this

```
$gender = isset( $user['gender'] ) ? $user['gender'] : '' ;
```